# Why does this PHP code print out-of-order?

Tags: php, echo

I am learning PHP OOP and I'm trying a few examples by myself. This example runs, but its output is unexpected:

**Class.php**:

```
class Member
{
  public $username = "Default";
  private $prop1 = "I'm a class property!";

  private $loggedIn = false; 

  public function login() {
    $this->loggedIn = true;
  }

  public function logout() {
    $this->loggedIn = false;
  }

  public function isLoggedIn() {
    return $this->loggedIn;
  }

  public function isLoggedIn2() {
    if ($this->loggedIn == 1){
    echo "connected";   
    } else {echo "not connected";}
  }
}

?>
```

**index.php**:

```
$member = new Member;
$member -> username = "FRED";
echo $member->username . " is " . ( $member->isLoggedIn() ? "logged in" : "logged out " ) . ($member->isLoggedIn2()) . " test " . "<br>";
```

**Expected Output:**

> FRED is logged out test **Not connected**

**Actual Output:**

> **Not connected**FRED is logged out test

Why does index.php write the result of `isLoggedIn2()` at the beginning instead of at the end?

Comment: You might want to improve your title to make it describe your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  public function isLoggedIn2() {
    if ($this->loggedIn == 1){
    echo "connected";   
    } else {echo "not connected";}
  }
```

You `echo` it out, so this gets printed whenever the function is called. Instead you should use `return` as in the other methods.

```
  public function isLoggedIn2() {
    if ($this->loggedIn)
        return "connected"; 
    else
        return "not connected";
  }
```

---

Why was it printed how it was? You have quite a complex statement here:

```
echo $member->username . " is " . 
  ( $member->isLoggedIn() ? "logged in" : "logged out " ) .
  $member->isLoggedIn2() . " test " . "<br>";
```

In order to actually print this, PHP first needs to know, what exactly to print. `$member->username` and the strings (*is*, *test*, etc.) are known, so no need to worry.

But every method needs to be called, to know its return value. If you used regular `return` there is nothing to worry, because you can place it where you need it. But since you `echo`ed it out inside the method, it gets printed whenever the method is called.

So what happens here is that PHP calls every method and **after** that tries to print it. That is why "*Not connected*" got printed before everything else.

Comment: So from your explanation I understand, that because an object was created with an echo statement in it already, the results were printed first, then I fed the value of Fred which came second, isLogged in last because it had a return. So for example if I was to turn all returns into echo, they would appear in order of execution when object is created?

Comment: @DavidSmith I tried to elaborate in my post. It doesn't matter when the object was created, but when the method was called. You could have `if($member->isLoggedIn2()) {}` and it would still print - because in order to know, if the condition is true, the method needs to be called - and whenever that is, the text gets printed

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
public function isLoggedIn2() { 
  if ($this->loggedIn == true ) { 
    echo "connected"; 
  } 
  else {
    echo "not connected";
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions that are used in an expression should use `return`, not `echo`. The problem is that the `isLoggedIn2` function is echoing its message while the argument list to `echo` is being calculated. Change it to:

```
public function isLoggedIn2() {
    if ($this->loggedIn) {
        return "connected";
    } else {
        return "not connected";
    }
}
```

This has nothing to do with OOP. You need to do the same thing with an ordinary function.

Answer (score 1):

```
  public function isLoggedIn2() {
    if ($this->loggedIn == 1){
    return true;   
    } else {return false;}
  } 

$member = new Member;
$member->username = "FRED";
$member->login(); // make login
echo $member->username . " is " . ( $member->isLoggedIn() ? "logged in" : "logged out " ) . ($member->isLoggedIn2()) . " test " . "<br>";

$member->logout(); // make logout
echo $member->username . " is " . ( $member->isLoggedIn() ? "logged in" : "logged out " ) . ($member->isLoggedIn2()) . " test " . "<br>";
```

Comment: What is the advantage of a 2nd method in this code, as it does the same as `isLoggedIn()`?